# match date in mysql and give result

Tags: php, mysql

I have written query in mysql as

```
select * from tblstafftasks as tst join tblstafftaskassignees as tsta on tsta.taskid = tst.id join tblstaff as ts on ts.staffid = tsta.staffid where tst.startdate like '2016-07-21' or '2016-07-21' between tst.startdate and tst.duedate and tst.rel_id = 1
```

My database looks like :

[image]

When I have written above query it runs perfect but does not give any result.

Here I have used **2016-07-21** that match with the startdate so it not give any result. So what query should I have to write to get result if it match with the startdate.?

Here i pass date in simple Y-m-d format and in database it store as datetime so help me to solve this query.

Comment: `tst.startdate like '2016-07-21' or '2016-07-21'` is this subquery correct?

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't see the rest of SQL. To convert datetimes, you can use DATE() function. Ex: `'2016-07-21' between DATE(tst.startdate) and DATE(tst.duedate)` or `DATE(tst.startdate) like '2016-07-21'`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to compare a date with `DATETIME` data types. If you want to compare just with the date of the `DATETIME` field, do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblstafftasks AS tst
JOIN tblstafftaskassignees AS tsta ON tsta.taskid = tst.id
JOIN tblstaff AS ts ON ts.staffid = tsta.staffid
WHERE DATE(tst.startdate) <= '2016-07-21'
AND DATE(tst.duedate) >= '2016-07-21'
```

Comment: its working i have to use **`** sign with column name and table name